# "No Connected Devices", trying to connect my LG to my Ubuntu machine

Tags: android, linux, connection, usb, lg

I am trying to run an app that I have built on my phone. I have enabled USB-debugging mode on my LG G3, but my Linux Machine and Android Studio is saying that there are no connected devices.

How do I fix this? Have I forgotten something important?

Answer (score 42):

I had the same connection problem.
Switching to "Send Images (PTP)" solved it for me.

Comment: Solved it for me too on a MAC mini

Comment: This solution works, android device immediately share security keys with ubuntu device. Great solution! :P

Comment: You just saved my life after half a day of googling and installing at least 10 different drivers. On Android 5 "file transfer" also worked. But after updating to Nougat apparently "photo transfer" needs to be selected. After plugging in and plugging out the phone again, it requested the RSA fingerprint and everything was working fine.

Comment: Perfect! Life saver!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my Xperia S.

1) I installed android adb tools on Ubuntu. (Using: sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot) 
2) Selected MTP mode on my Xperia S. Disabled debugging. Disconnected the phone from system.
3) Enabled USB debugging, connected the phone again and tried the command "adb devices" from ubuntu terminal.

It then started the adb daemon and listed my device.
Once the device was listed there, I started the android studio again, and my phone was listed there.

Also, you might find this helpful : https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

CD to your sdk platform-tools folder

Check if adb sees your device

./adb devices

If it displays 'List of devices attached' and a blank line below, then restart adb as follows:

./adb kill-server ./adb start-server

then re-run ./adb devices and see if it picks up the device, eg as follows:

List of devices attached xxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-written and detailed step-by-step guide for connecting a phone with Android Studio when running Linux here:

http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Changing in the **USB Options** on the phone to "**Send Images (PTP)**" worked to me as well (on a LG phone). Must be something with LG phones, because with other Android phones this wasn't needed.

Answer (score -2):

After taking a few hours, I just solved a similar problem minutes ago with LG G3 on WINDOWS.

Maybe my experience can help you.

Firstly, do NOT enable USB debugging.
Secondly, install the OFFICIAL USB driver from LG (I have no idea whether this is available on Ubuntu). Please make sure the driver works normally by some LG software. BTW, I don't think LG is good at software.
Thirdly, enable USB debugging and go.

Comment: This is pretty much irrelevant.  ADB on Linux (or for that matter OSX) does not utilize any "driver" apart from the ADB program itself.  Only Windows requires a device driver for basic USB peripheral access.